# Grails Plugin Development - override domain class

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

Plugins in Grails are great method to modularise an application.The documentation suggest to override the artifacts from the plugin in the application, which uses this plugin.

Is it realy the best approach?

Let's describe it by example: There is a domain class "org.User" defined in the plugin. The application overrides this domain class. If I use "grails run-app" then there are no warnings and it works. But Eclipse (GGTS) complains about "Invalid duplicate class definition of class org.User". For some developers it wouldn't matter, but I like the IDE helping on coding by stuf like "autocomplete".

At the end both classes are compiled an put on the java class loader. The application version of the class is loaded before the version of the plugin. The class resolver finds it first and that's why it works. Please correct me if I'm wrong at this point. Is it realy a good idea to have two versions of a class in one class loader?

What are the alternatives?

Comment: Although there should not be any issue, since plugins are compiled first than the app, what is the need to override the domain class in app? Is the plugin not able to do what you expect it to do?

Comment: In my example the plugin is handling all the autorisation/authentification stuf. In the application there are additional fields in domain "User", which are not relevant for security. BTW: By extending the User using inheritance, there are some issues in views and controlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like `Spring Security Core` plugin does, provide the `User` class as a template, so your application that use this plugin can choose between creating his own class or installing your default User class.

The plugin user template is [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/templates/Person.groovy.template), and the script responsible to create this in the application is [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/scripts/S2Quickstart.groovy).

You will need also a config value to know the class to use, and use it dynamic.

P.S: there are good security plugins like Shiro and Spring Security, maybe it's easier to check them instead of create your own.

Comment: Thanks for advice! The Spring Security Core plugin uses scripts to generate the artifacts. This is the second option described here http://grails.github.io/grails-howtos/en/pluginDevelopmentBestPractices.html#s4. Would you say it should be the prefered way to create plugin artifacts?

Comment: Yes, scripts are the preferred way to create plugin artifacts that can be configurable. If it's a static functionality like a controller action that you don't want your user to change, then you can provide it directly, without creating a script.

Comment: Links provided in this answer are out-of-date